# Convert string Data without change a Full String

Tags: php

Real Output:

```
$hour=$pk['openingHoursEnglish'];

"Mon - Fri: 0800-2100, Sat: 0900-2000"
```

I Want it Like,

```
"Mon - Fri: 08:00-21:00, Sat: 09:00-20:00"
```

Comment: I retrieve a data from json where value of time is "Mon - Fri: 0800-2100, Sat: 0900-2000", but i have to display it as a  "Mon - Fri: 08:00-21:00, Sat: 09:00-20:00" , in a Time() format....

Comment: So you know you have to convert it. What have you already done to achieve this beside getting the value out of a json file? Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like below:

```
$str = "Mon - Fri: 0800-2100, Sat: 0900-2000";
$line = preg_replace_callback( '/\d{4}/', function ($matches) {
    return implode( ':', str_split( $matches [0], 2 ) );
}, $str );

var_dump( $line, $str );
```

this is my test online:
[Demo](https://eval.in/637470)

I hope to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeap, Sir thank You so much it's working perfectly ....
again thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript to split the string  before displaying it from the Json file.To do so,you can use [JavaScript String split() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)